# Index position understanding, java

Tags: java, loops, indexing, substring, contains

I am struggling to understand what is occurring in this code, I understand Java only has positive indexing.

Example of what I am attempting to understand.

```
            if ((Input.length() > 2) &&
                (Input.substring(1, Input.length() -2).contains(substring))) {
                System.out.print("Middle");
```

What is the above code doing?

Comment: There's no negative indexing in your code. The end index of your substring is `Input.length()-2`, which is a positive number. I'm not clear why you're posting a Java question with Java code about negative indexing when as you say Java does not use negative indexing.

Comment: How is -2 a positive number?  I'm failing to see how -2 e.g. the "-" equates to a positive number?

Comment: it's not -2, it's Input.length() -2.

Comment: `Input.length()` is greater than 2, as asserted by the if statement.  If `Input.length()` is 2, `2-2=0`.  If it is 3, `3-2=1`, and so on.

Comment: `Input.length()-2` is a positive number because `Input.length()` is greater than 2.

Comment: I think the lack of a space after the minus sign is confusing you.  This is a perfect example of why whitespace matters.

Comment: So for clarification sake, We are beginning at Index 1, E.g. B, 
We are then subtracting the last two letters from the input String length. 
Example. 
String = ("ABCDE");
Begin at index 1 = B, 
Subtract 2 from length, 
Therefore string is now BC?

As stated struggling but this clears a lot up.

Comment: Yup, you got it.

Answer (score 1):

There are no negative indexes in Java.

Let's take your example code.  I've formatted the code to make it easier to see what's happening.

```
if ((Input.length() > 2) &&
       (Input.substring(1, Input.length() - 2).contains(substring))) {
                System.out.print("Middle");
}
```

The field Input should be lower case (input).

The if is saying if the String length of input > 2 and if the substring from position 1 to position length, where length is the length of the string, minus 2.

So if the string is 5 characters (as an example), it would be longer than 2, and the substring would be the characters in positions 1 and 2.  Length of 5 minus 2 gives 3.  Since 3 is the end index of the substring, we stop the substring at position 2.

Using the example String of "ABCDE", the length is greater than 2, and the substring to be tested (contains) is "BC".  The String is still "ABCDE".

The substring with the parenthesis is a String method.  The substring in the contains method is a field that contains a String value.  They are two different concepts even though they have the same name.